# angularjs popup is not working with routing template and controller

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to create popup to display some information.I am using routing.My code is running good when I run the code without routing.But when I run the code with routing template and controller there is no error but my code is not working.It is not displaying the popup when user click on button.I want the popup display when user click on the button.

```
    <html ng-app="Demo">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color:black;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#/home" style="color:white;">Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="#/product" style="color:white;">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/students" style="color:white;">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/students" style="color:white;">Contact </a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <ng-view></ng-view>

    </body>
    </html>

script.js

    var app = angular.module("Demo",['ngRoute'])
            .config(function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                           .when("/",{
                   templateUrl: "Templates/home.html",
                   controller: "homeController"         
                })
                .when("/home",{
                   templateUrl: "Templates/home.html",
                   controller: "homeController"         
                })
                .when("/product",{
                   templateUrl: "Templates/product.html",
                   controller: "coursesController"          
                })
                .when("/students",{
                   templateUrl: "Templates/students.html",
                   controller: "studentsController"         
                })
            })
                angular.module('PopupDemo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
                angular.module('PopupDemo').controller('homeController', ['$scope','$modal',function ($scope, $modal) {
                    $scope.open = function () {
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                          controller: 'PopupCont',
                                      templateUrl: 'Popup.html',
                            });
                        }
                }])

            .controller('PopupCont', ['$scope','$modalInstance',function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.close = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
        }]);
            app.controller("coursesController",function($scope){
            $scope.courses = ["C#","VB.NET","SQL Server","ASP.NET","hi","hello"];
            })
            app.controller("studentsController",function($scope){
            $scope.students = ["C#","VB.NET","SQL Server","ASP.NET"];
            })
home.html


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angularjs popup</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="PopupDemo">
    <div ng-controller="homeController">
    {{message1}}
    <center><h2>Angularjs-Popup</h2></center>
    <center><button ng-click="open()" class="btn btn-warning">Popup With Close</button></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal-header">
<h3 class="modal-title">Header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
Popup example with close button
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"
ng-click="close()">Close</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>


    Help me please thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one **ng-app**, lets say the **Demo** app, and inject **PopupDemo** module to it. Try:

```
<html ng-app="Demo">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
  <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color:black;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#/home" style="color:white;">Home </a></li>
          <li><a href="#/product" style="color:white;">Product</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/students" style="color:white;">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/students" style="color:white;">Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>

</html>

script.js

<script>
var app = angular.module('Demo', ['ngRoute', 'PopupDemo'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "Templates/home.html",
        controller: "homeController"
      })
      .when("/home", {
        templateUrl: "Templates/home.html",
        controller: "homeController"
      })
      .when("/product", {
        templateUrl: "Templates/product.html",
        controller: "coursesController"
      })
      .when("/students", {
        templateUrl: "Templates/students.html",
        controller: "studentsController"
      })
  });

angular.module('PopupDemo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('PopupDemo').controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      controller: 'PopupCont',
      templateUrl: 'Popup.html',
    });
  }
}]);
app.controller("coursesController", function($scope) {
  $scope.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "SQL Server", "ASP.NET", "hi", "hello"];
})
app.controller("studentsController", function($scope) {
  $scope.students = ["C#", "VB.NET", "SQL Server", "ASP.NET"];
})
</script>

home.html

<div>
  <div ng-controller="homeController">
    {{message1}}
    <center>
      <h2>Angularjs-Popup</h2></center>
    <center>
      <button ng-click="open()" class="btn btn-warning">Popup With Close</button>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,I have made the change but its give error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=Demo&p1=Error%3A%20…0%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A359)

Comment: i need more details

Comment: Hi, I edited my code.Please go through it.If any thing more you want to know please ask.